# Limits of $n^{p/n}$ and $(n!)^{1/n}$

Tags: calculus

> Determine the limits (i) $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n^{p/n}$ where $p\in\mathbb{R}$, and (ii) $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(n!)^{1/n}.$

For (i), I will prove that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n^{p/n}=1$ when $p\geq 0$. Since $n^{-p/n} = 1/n^{p/n}$, it will follow, because $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \dfrac{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(x)}{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}g(x)}$ that the limit is $1$ when $p<0$ as well.

Let $n^{p/n} = 1+x_n$. Then $n^p = (1+x_n)^n$. Let $k$ be an integer such that $k>p$, and consider $n>k$. We have $$n^p = (1+x_n)^n > \dbinom{n}{k}x_n^k,$$ so that $$x_n<\left(\frac{k!\cdot n^p}{n(n-1)\ldots(n-k+1)}\right)^{1/k}$$

Since $k$ is fixed, the numerator is a polynomial in $n$ with degree $p$, and the denominator has degree $k>p$, the right-hand side converges to $0$.

This should work, but seems rather messy for me. Is there a nicer way to settle it?

Also, I'm guessing that for (ii), $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(n!)^{1/n} = 1$ also, but starting in the same way using $n!=(1+x_n)^n$ doesn't seem to lead anywhere.

Comment: For the second, Stirling will be very helpful, if you are allowed to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this technique for both problems 
$$ n^{p/n} = e^{\frac{p}{n}\ln(n)} = \dots  $$

$$ (n!)^{1/n}= e^{\frac{1}{n}\ln(n!)} \sim e^{ \frac{1}{n}(n\ln(n)-n+1) } \longrightarrow_{n\to \infty}\,\infty.   $$

**Note:**

> $$ \ln(n!)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln(k)\sim \int_{1}^{n} \ln(x)dx \sim n\ln(n)-n+1. $$

Comment: Wow, so $(e^p)^{\frac{\ln n}{n}}$ converges to $1$ because ${\frac{\ln n}{n}}$ converges to $0$, very nice!

Comment: @PJMiller: Yes. You are right.

Comment: $n!$ is much easier than that. $n!=(n\cdot 1)((n-1)\cdot 2)\dots > \left(n\right)^{n/2}$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: This is a systematic technique to solve the problem. No guessing is in here.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Who's guessing?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews He means that this is a general technique that allows you to do these kinds of problems without much effort. There is no need to "guess" at the method you should use.

Answer (score 3):

As you have pointed out, it is sufficient to consider $p\geq 0$.

$$(1)$$

$$\text{AM-GM:}$$

$$1\leq n^{\frac{p}{n}}\leq \left(\frac{n-2+2\sqrt{n}}{n}\right)^p=\left(1-\frac{2}{n}+\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^p\to 1$$

$$(2)$$

$$n!^{\frac{p}{n}}\sim \left[\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)\sqrt[2n]{2\pi n}\right]^p\to\infty$$

Comment: I must be missing something, but how do you apply AM-GM there?

Comment: @PJMiller $\underbrace{1+1+\cdots +1}_{n-2}+\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n}$

Comment: That's an interesting (and nice) use!

Answer (score 2):

For ii) you can use Stirling's approximation $n! \sim \left( \frac{n}{e} \right)^n \sqrt{2\pi n}$ to show that your limit equals $\infty$.